# Is there a way to obtain the Total Pages from PDF File inside an <object> tag HTML in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, pdf, pdfobject

I am trying to obtain the total Pages that my PDF file has when its opened in a  tag.

When I press the menu --> Document Properties it shows me information from the document and one of it is the Total pages:
[Document Properties][1]
[Total Pages][2]

Also it shows in the 1/n pages selector.
[Page Selector ][3]

I was trying to read the input id that has the total value, but I am not able to run the code after it finish loading the file.

`let totalPages =  document.getElementById("pagelength");`

And when adding the onload tag on the  I am getting that there is no definition of that function.

`<object #pdfview  [data]='pdffile'  type="application/pdf"  width="100%"  height="100%" onload="cargue()"  >`

[No definition Image][4]

Its there a way to get that number? I am currently using Angular 17.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1v09.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3clr.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gEMq.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkCKS.png